# MSSQL database server on UNIX

Tags: database, sqlserver

I have heard rumors, but did not manage to find anything more, about some sort of MSSQL serving on UNIX machine, or MSSQL/MySQL server, that can handle MSSQL storage.

I would like to know, if it is possible, and what are possible methods to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you want that if it existed? If SQL Server fits your database needs best, run it in its native environment. Note that SQL Server is closely related to Sybase which does run on Unix-type systems. I wouldn't be surprised if their storage engines had some degree of compatibility before SQL Server 7. (And possibly still do.)

Comment: @Mat There are some MSSQL based software, that I want to make run on UNIX machine.

Answer (score 1):

12 years later, it turns out Microsoft actually offers versions of SQL Server 2017, 2019 and 2022 for Linux:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-overview?view=sql-server-ver16

They even offer a package repository covering quite a few distributions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linux/packages

https://packages.microsoft.com/

Not everything is available for every distribution equally, but the installation of SQL Server 2022 is documented for RHEL 8.x and 9.x, SLES 15 SP3, and Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.